# Data insertion into database after clicking onto button

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I would like to **insert** some data into my **database using laravel eloquent** after pressing a button.

My controller, controller method, route, js files are ready.

I just don't know how to connect these together.

**Should i fire an event after clicking the button, if yes how can i do that using blade ?**

I have a main page and form like this.

This is my main page :

```
{{ Form::open(array('action'=>'Mycontroller@myMethod')) }}

  <!--Some html here !-->
  <div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="btn btn-success" id="add" onclick="">
         Here is my button
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 


{{ Form::close() }}
```

I need to insert some data after clicking this button. How can i do this ? As like i said all my routes controller and function are ready for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to use PHP or jQuery to send your data to the backend?

Comment: @JMc jQuery would be better because if i choose php i won't be able to use laravel properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have your form set up, all you have to do is add a submit button and you will go to Mycontroller@myMethod when the submit button is called on.

```
// submit button
{{ Form::submit('Submit') }}
```

Then in your myMethod(), you can call this

```
$data = Input::all();
```

to get the form data.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, `Input::all()` shouldn't be used, instead use `Input::only()`.